# Sending and receiving files with PHP SOAP and MTOM

Tags: php, web-services, soap, mtom

What I am trying to do is to send and receive files using MTOM with PHP and SOAP.
There is a SOAP webservice written in JAVA that I can play without problem, except for files.

I tried almost everything (patching Nusoap, changing the `__doRequest` in [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/class.soapclient)) without success.

Is there any implementation of the MTOM specification in PHP?

---

*Edit:* Here is what I did :

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) 
{
    $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);

    // parse $response, extract the multipart messages and so on

    // this part removes stuff 
    $start           = strpos($response, '<?xml');
    $end             = strrpos($response, '>');
    $response_string = substr($response, $start, $end - $start + 1);
    return ($response_string);
}
```

Here is what I get :

```
--uuid:06cccc9f-7827-40f4-ad42-ccd60a85fba2
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:telechargerRelevesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://xxx/GestionReception/v1.0"><return><attachmentFile><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:98c24cf6-c72d-45f0-8b66-bf72e53670fb-168@cxf.apache.org"/></attachmentFile><dateReception>2013-05-30T14:04:08.000+02:00</dateReception><fileName>TEST-RELEVE2013053014041310846.RLV</fileName><idReception>36</idReception></return><return><attachmentFile><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:98c24cf6-c72d-45f0-8b66-bf72e53670fb-169@cxf.apache.org"/></attachmentFile><dateReception>2013-05-30T14:03:42.000+02:00</dateReception><fileName>TEST-RELEVE2013053014034873259.RLV</fileName><idReception>35</idReception></return></ns2:telechargerRelevesResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:06cccc9f-7827-40f4-ad42-ccd60a85fba2
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <98c24cf6-c72d-45f0-8b66-bf72e53670fb-168@cxf.apache.org>

0111311    00001EUR2 00000000001  030113                                                  0000000384770G                0411311    00001EUR2E0000000000106060113  060113VIREMENT EMIS                    00000000 0000000005446NVIREMENT EMIS   0411311    00001EUR2E0000000000162060113  060113FRAIS SUR VIREMENT EMIS          00000000 0000000000001QFRAIS SUR VIREME0411311    00001EUR2E0000000000106060113  060113VIREMENT EMIS                    00000000
```

Comment: Changing `__doRequest` for `SoapClient` should normally suffice. Double check you didn't do any error with that. How did you do it btw, where is that code? Specs are here: [SOAP Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (W3C Rec Jan 2005)](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/)

Comment: Here is what I did :
    `public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
    $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        // parse $response, extract the multipart messages and so on
        
        //this part removes stuff
        $start=strpos($response,'<?xml');
        $end=strrpos($response,'>');    
        $response_string=substr($response,$start,$end-$start+1);
        return($response_string);
    }`

But I am using WSSE too, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Well I won't consider this code to be working. Do you see the first comment in there? The `// parse $response, extract the multipart messages and so on`? You need to *provide* that code that does so. However in your code this is missing. That is actually why I have asked.

Comment: Thanks, well so I don't have the part of code that extract the multipart message ...

Comment: A more generic description is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism pointing to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-binary_Optimized_Packaging which has some examples of the data. Looks like you need a Mime Parser. Just dump the response to a file first. Then create a new script that uses `file_get_contents` on that file to retrieve it again and some some *MIME-parser* (there exist some) to de-compose the multi-part message (it's worth to learn about that because this is also how email works). That should bring you a huge step forward.

Comment: One exemplary Mime library is given here: [Read MIME data using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1183744/367456)

Comment: Ok, I will try with this, thanks.

Comment: What you've got so far in the code-example is just not stable. I wouldn't do it that way because it's too easy to break. Better write that file and present it here so that it's clear that you have the mime problem (and not something different)

Comment: I posted the file I got when calling the webservice.

Comment: That is mime. If possible (don't know, probably not if it contains secret data), can you link the whole response as some file? it looks cuttet. And yes again, that is mime encoding. Here you would need to get the parts and also the binary data. Perhaps you need to zip that file.

Comment: No, it's only test so here is the file : http://demo.ovh.eu/fr/affb9793f486ac10c6762dfd1b70d96e/

Comment: hmm this misses the overall boundary headers. Those are perhaps cut away by PHPs `SoapClient`. Can you show the rawResponse  as well? http://www.php.net/soapclient.getlastresponse this might show a bit more information. Same for response headers please. (this might get a bit technical for your taste, but I'm confident you can dig it :))

Comment: Here is the file updated with your answer : http://demo.ovh.eu/fr/d1f9bbae3f44e2021abbe5e7db611bbb/
Here is the soap call : 
`$this->_wsSoapClient = new WsSoapClient('https://XXX/app/post-ws/GestionReception/v1.0?wsdl',
            array(
                'wsdl_cache' => 1,
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => 0,
                'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1
                )
                );`

i have to activate the trace to 1, otherwise I have no answer, maybe it could help...